# How can I use tryCatch to count errors in a while try loop

Tags: r

I want to be able to count my error/non-convergence from my lm model, which the try function skips, using a `tryCatch`, I will give an example of my code below so someone can help.

```
i =- 0
count = 0
count1 = 0
fit = rep(NA, 1000)

while(i < 1000) try({ 
    count1 = count1 + 1
    dat = sample(data,replace = T)
    fit[i] = lm(y~x1 + x2, data = dat)
    count <- count + 1
}, silent = T)
```

I have this code above that runs smoothly but sometimes because I resample the data, model does not converge and hence the use of `try` function, and I need to count the number of times that the model doesnt converge.

I tried putting count1 and count before and after the model and they are all counting 1000. But I know for sure that some of the models don't converge and give errors (thus if `x1` categorical is such that it has only one level instead of two levels after resampling then we have errors).

Can someone help me how I can use `tryCatch` inside this while loop to be able to solve this 
problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this (and you need to increment your `while` loop):

```
i <- 1
count1 <- 0
fit <- rep(NA, 1000)

while(i <= 1000) { 
    dat <- sample(data, replace = T)
    temp <- try(lm(y~x1 + x2, data = dat))
    if(inherits(temp,"try-error"))
        count1 <- count1 + 1
    else
        fit[i] <- temp
    i <- i + 1
}
```